# how to detect website leaking data

Tags: wordpress

I have recently built a website based on WordPress. I got a free theme from a source in Pakistan.

I have to use this theme because it perfectly serves my purpose. But I want to know that if this theme is quietly establishing a connection with another server and sending my data.

How can I detect that my website is internally sending some codes to the server of developer of theme?  Also, I need to know what servers are being communicated with — like, if any image is getting loaded from their server, any code is imported from their server, or anything else is being fetched from their server to run.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the source code, then you can simply look what this theme does - basically theme should only be HTML and CSS (or mostly it). If there is too much suspicious PHP of Javascript I wouldn't use it.

If you want to see if it connects to some outside sources, run it in your controlled environment and use some network sniffing tool like Wireshark for example.

Generally speaking - if you don't trust the source where you got your theme and you are not good enough in programming to check for malicious code yourselves, don't use it!

I would recommend downloading some of themes provided directly by wordpress.org - those should be safe.

Comment: that is where I am a layman. its a big theme with hundreds of files. Also the wireshark program has ended (according to their website).

Comment: oh man, you scared me :-) Wireshark did not end, only their festival did :-)

Comment: please see edits to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am going to try wireshark to get the details.